# Clustered Columnstore Index on Table with Foreign key

Tags: sql-server, index, sql-server-2014, columnstore

Using SQL Server 2014, I am trying to create a clustered columnstore index on a table which is referenced by a foreign key.

This is the syntax I am using

```
CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_Variant 
  ON dbo.Variant WITH (DROP_EXISTING = ON)
```

And I get this error

> CREATE INDEX statement failed. A clustered columnstore index cannot be created over referencing column 'FK_Variant_Price' on table 'Variant'.

Any suggestions? I have looked online but cannot find anything.

Comment: What version are you using? SQL Server 2014 Columnstore does not allow you to have foreign keys or any constraints for that matter

Comment: I am SQL 2014. Thanks for clarifying foreign key constraints restrictions.